Unable to get changes in General Model Change Events
I have tried to build an asyncua opcua server which triggers General Model Change Event but when it is connected with client it gives "None" in changes even though nodes are added and removed.
Following is the server code:
uri = "http://examples.freeopcua.github.io"
idx = await server.register_namespace(uri)
objects_node = server.nodes.objects
my_object = await objects_node.add_object(idx, "MyObject")
node_ids = []
evtype = server.get_node("ns=0;i=2133")
myevgen = await server.get_event_generator(evtype,my_object)
async with server:
    for i in range(5):
        node = await my_object.add_variable(idx, f"Node{i+1}", 0)
        node_ids.append(node.nodeid)
        await node.set_writable()
        print(f"Added node: {node}")
        await myevgen.trigger()
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
    node_to_remove = random.choice(node_ids)
    node_ids.remove(node_to_remove)
    server.delete_nodes([node_to_remove])
    await myevgen.trigger()
    print(f"Removed node: {node_to_remove}")

    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)

Updated code:
    my_object = await objects_node.add_object(idx, "MyObject")
node_ids = []
evtype = server.get_node("ns=0;i=2133")
myevgen = await server.get_event_generator(evtype,my_object)
changes = []
async with server:
    for i in range(5):
        node = await my_object.add_variable(idx, f"Node{i+1}", 0)
        node_ids.append(node.nodeid)
        changes.append(ua.ModelChangeStructureDataType(node.nodeid, ua.NodeId(), 0))
        print(changes)
        await node.set_writable()
        print(f"Added node: {node}")
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
    myevgen.event.Message = ua.LocalizedText("addresspace update")
    myevgen.event.Severity = 100
    myevgen.event.Changes = changes
    await myevgen.trigger()   

    

    # if random.random() < 0.5:
    # node_to_remove = random.choice(node_ids)
    # node_ids.remove(node_to_remove)
    # await server.delete_nodes([node_to_remove])
    # await myevgen.trigger()
    # print(f"Removed node: {node_to_remove}")

    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)

Client output:
Event Notification: Event(['Changes:None', "EventId:b'c65319e5b1c44a1e8dbf3d193d65d254'", 'EventType:NodeId(Identifier=2133, NamespaceIndex=0, NodeIdType=<NodeIdType.FourByte: 1>)', 'SourceNode:NodeId(Identifier=1, NamespaceIndex=2, NodeIdType=<NodeIdType.FourByte: 1>)', 'SourceName:MyObject', 'Time:2024-12-02 04:23:24.019891+00:00', 'ReceiveTime:2024-12-02 04:23:24.019891+00:00', 'LocalTime:TimeZoneDataType(Offset=330, DaylightSavingInOffset=True)', 'Message:LocalizedText(Locale=None, Text=None)', 'Severity:1'])

You should pass a 1 to: changes.append(ua.ModelChangeStructureDataType(node.nodeid, ua.NodeId(), 1))

Giving me AttributeError: 'NodeId' object has no attribute 'name'at myevgen.event.Changes = changes. After doing above changes.

or try changes.append(ua.ModelChangeStructureDataType(node.nodeid, ua.NodeId(), ua.Byte(1)))

Sry my bad 0 -> Node added. Your code should work. What client are you using?

We are using asyncua client which subscribe to the event.

First, from the server code, you've done a number of things, including registering a namespace, adding objects, adding variables, triggering events, and deleting nodes. However, in the event notification received by the client, Changes:None is displayed, which means that no changes to the model were detected. One possible reason is that the setup or notification mechanism for event triggers is faulty in some way. For example: 1. Check whether the related parameters are set correctly when the event is triggered to ensure that the event can correctly carry the change information.
2. Verify that the server has correctly updated the state of the model after adding and removing nodes, and pass the changed state to the event generator. You also need to check the client's processing logic to see if it can correctly parse and recognize the event notifications sent by the server.
In general, the logic of handling event triggers and model changes on the server side, as well as the process of receiving and parsing event notifications on the client side, needs to be carefully examined to determine the problem.

Asyncua doens't support automatic generation of ModelChangeEvent. If you want your client to know you have generate the events your self.
You can read about the events in the Spec.
To generate the events your code can look like this:
  change_gen = await server.get_event_generator(BaseModelChangeEvent())
  change_gen.event.Message = ua.LocalizedText("MyFirstEvent %d" % count)
  change_gen.event.Severity = 100
  await change_gen.trigger()

Update: You could signal the client every node changed like this:
  change_gen = await server.get_event_generator(GeneralModelChangeEvent())
  changes = []
  ....
  # Adding a node
  node = await my_object.add_variable(idx, f"Node{i+1}", 0)
    node_ids.append(node.nodeid)
  changes.append(ua.ModelChangeStructureDataType(node.nodeid, ua.NodeId(), ua.Byte(0))
  .... 
  # removing a node
  node_to_remove = ...
  await server.delete_nodes([node_to_remove])
  changes.append(ua.ModelChangeStructureDataType(node.nodeid, ua.NodeId(), ua.Byte(1))
  ....
  # generating the event
  change_gen.event.Message = ua.LocalizedText("addresspace update")
  change_gen.event.Severity = 100
  change_gen.event.Changes = changes
  await change_gen.trigger()

Here is also the spec for ModelChangeStrureDataType

I have generated the event in provided server code. Still unable to get the changes.

Updated my example with GeneralModelChangeEvent where the nodes a specified

Updated my code but still output shows as Changes:'None'
